# c# stuck on generics and interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I don't understand why the below code doesn't work in c# (.NET Core 1.1).

```
public interface IChild
{
}

public interface IParent
{
    IEnumerable<IChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ParentBase<TChild> : IParent
    where TChild : IChild
{
    public IEnumerable<TChild> Children {get; set; }
}
```

The error message is

> Error CS0738  'ParentBase< TChild>' does not implement interface member 'IParent.Children'. 'ParentBase< TChild>.Children' cannot implement 'IParent.Children' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerable< IChild>'.

The error message says the IEnumerable< TChild> is not of type IEnumerable< IChild> while I constrain TChild to IChild.

I found two 'easy' ways out of this, but both require rather bad changes in the client code.  I load an entire object tree of these types using ConfigurationSection.Bind() in the client code.

Unwanted solution 1 : Make the parent interface generic

```
public interface IChild
{
}

public interface IParent<TChild>
    where TChild : IChild
{
    IEnumerable<TChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ParentBas<TChild> : IParent<TChild>
    where TChild : IChild
{
    public IEnumerable<TChild> Children {get; set; }
}
```

Unwanted solution 2 :

```
public interface IChild
{
}

public interface IParent
{
    IEnumerable<IChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ParentBas<TChild> : IParent
    where TChild : IChild
{
    public IEnumerable<IChild> Children {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why you using generic `ParentBas<TChild>`? You don't need it - `IEnumerable<IChild> Children` already accept all implementations of `IChild`?

Comment: *"I don't understand why the below code doesn't work in c#"* - because it would lead to an inconsistency between the interface and the concrete class, for example allowing to add a dog child to a cat parent through the interface

Comment: Well, ParentBas is missspelled, it should be ParentBase.  The purpose of having an abstract Parent base class is to implement common functionality for the Parent in there.  I have remove that common code for clarity.

Comment: Your question is exactly like all the other questions already on Stack Overflow confusing inheritance of types with inheritance of type parameters. See marked duplicate for a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is pretty is simple:

```
public interface Animal { }

public interface ICage
{
   IEnumerable<IAnimal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Cage<TAnimal> where Animal: Animal
{
    public IEnumerable<TAnimal> { get; set; } //Illegal implementation of ICage
}
```

Ok, this is basically the same set up without some unnecessary cruft. Now see what happens if what you are trying were a legal implementation of the interface:

```
var dogCage = new Cage<Dog>();
dogCage.Animals = new[] { cat }; //Illegal! Why?!?
```

Now, although that seems reasonable, it is a flagrant violation of the `ICage` contract. This should be and in fact is legal:

```
ICage dogCage = new Cage<Dog>();
dogCage.Animals = new[] { cat }; //Legal!
```

So, you can obviously see why your code does not satisfy the contract of `IParent` at all.

Comment: Sorry, not clear to me at all.  If dogCage is of type Cage<Dog> then adding cats to the Animals list should be illegal in both examples.  Still don't get why my declarations of IParent, IChild and ParentBase are illegal.

Comment: @StefaanVandevelde well because the interface `ICage` states it admits  *any* `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`, that includes `IEnumerable<Dog>`. With your proposal `Cage<Cat>` only admits `IEnumerable<Cat>`s. That violates the contract of `ICage`.

Comment: @StefaanVandevelde and that's the point precisely, your interface doesn't disallow anything, any `IAnimal` is valid, no matter what the generic type of the implementing class is. Why should the interface worry about `TAnimal`? It knows nothing about it...

Comment: OK, Yes, that makes sense